# i18n with ngrx store - translating angular application

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngrx, ngx-translate, ngrx-store-4.0

I'm writing to ask you for advice. We build store based angular application, which requires translation. The request is to use official angular i18n method, although I have no idea how to connect my translations with values from the store. Is it even possible, does anyone have any experience with this or should I straight away go to the solutions like ngx-translate library..? I must say I researched quite a bit, but have not found understandable (I'm a junior and it's pretty hard for me to grasps all pros, cons and what's possible) answers. So my request is to share your knowledge if you have any applicable experience. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tl;dr; Use Ngrx and I18n -- but don't store translations in Ngrx store.

So using Ngrx and the Angular platform I18n tools together is fine. That said, your translations won't be in the Ngrx store. The store is for application State. This state typically is backed from a data source.

The i18n translation are separate from the application state. The translations are statically compiled into the application at build time. This can be automated to place the Spanish build in dist/es/ and the french in dist/fr/ and so on.

Because it is compile time, there is no runtime translation that the state store can even touch.

Now this may change with Angular 6, where there may be a concept of runtime translations like in ngx-translate. That said, I still wouldn't put translations into the state store unless I was forced to because they come from a web service.

Comment: thanks a lot for your reply! do you know whether in this case I should just use i18n attribute like I do it with static values? will `ng xi18n` command  generate messages.xlf file with the outputted values from the store...?

Comment: Your translations are `copy` not data. The store is for data, the translation for copy. Example: you have a model containing a property, numberOfEggs: number. You can store that in the ngrx state. Now you want to display a translatable label for this data, "Number of Eggs" would be the string you include in your template with the i18n attribute. When you extract these into your locale xliff it will only contain the translation string, not any data.

Comment: hm, I understand. Thank you very much! Let me ask you last question, do you have any idea how I could loop through my translation?

Comment: Sara -- when you say loop through your translations, do you mean loop through the XLIFF file as part of the translation process? -- or do  you mean loop through them at runtime, within your Angular application? Why do you want to loop through your translations?

Comment: I'm sorry for not being clear. I mean creating translations for elements inside for loop like this:
`<div *ngFor="let item of items">
                 <label for="input_{{item}}">{{item}}</label>
                 <input type="radio" id="input_{{item}}" value="{{item}}" [formControl]="radioControl">
           </div>`
how could I translate several `{{item}}` that my loop will create... ?

Comment: Where do the items come from? Do you have a static list of all possible items in your code, or are they dynamic -- can be any random string?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164333/discussion-between-sara-and-martin).