# Where to translate with ngx-translate and ngrx in Angular 5?

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx, ngrx-store, ngx-translate

We have an application, that uses Redux-Pattern with [ngrx](https://github.com/ngrx/platform) as well as [ngx-translate](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core) for i18n. I already learned from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48551317/2725515) how to handle the Angular i18n approach together with ngrx, but I don't know where the ngx-translate-approach fits best into an ngrx application.

Translation can be done

- by service: `this.translateService.get('SOME_KEY')`
- or by pipe: `{{ 'SOME_KEY' | translate }}`

which offers four possible places, where keys can be translated:

1. in the component, before calling an action
2. in the action itself, before passing the data to the store
3. in the reducer
4. in the view, when a rerendering is triggered by a state change

**Where would you consider it the cleanest way to put the translation process?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ideally you'd put your translations in the template **first**, as this is closest to where the translation will appear.

If and when you find that you can't use the template to show some translation, you could then consider using the `translateService` in your components, services, etc.

BTW you can also use the `ngx-translate` **directive** for showing translations:

```html
<div [translate]="'SOME_OTHER_KEY'"></div>
```